# What is the point of sending timestamp?

Tags: security, digital-signature

So, as far as I understand here what is happening on digital signature:

```
Bob creates message and timestamp: M + Timestamp = L
Bob hashes the L: H(L)
Bob signs the H(L) with his private key: Sign(H(L))
Bob sends this signature and L to Alice: L || Sign(H(L))
Alice open H(L) with Bob's public key.
Alice hashes the L: H(L)
Alice compares if the H(L)s match.
If so source integrity has been established. Thus, we can ensure that message is sent by Bob.
```

So why do we include timestamp into message? We already know message is from Bob, what is the point of checking timestamp as if it is delayed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Alice checks the age of the message, and/or collects timestamps of already-received messages, she can defend against replay attacks.

A replay attack is when somebody has captured a genuine message from Bob but sends it again (or instead) at a later date.